# How can I wrap divs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

Basically, I want the inner divs outside the outer div to wrap according to the width of the outer div, which in turn expands and contracts according to the width of the browser window, like so:

```
.---------------------.
|                     | <-- Browser Window
| .-----------------. |
| |  ,-,  ,-,  ,-,  | |
| |  |X|  |X|  |X|  | |
| |  `-`  `-`  `-`  | |
| |                 | |
| |  ,-,  ,-,  ,-,  | |
| |  |X|  |X|  |X|  | |
| |  `-`  `-`  `-`  | |
| `-----------------` |
|                     |
`---------------------`

.-------------------------------.
|                               | <-- Browser Window enlarged
| .---------------------------. |
| |  ,-,  ,-,  ,-,  ,-,  ,-,  | |
| |  |X|  |X|  |X|  |X|  |X| <----- Inner divs wrap around accordingly, as if
| |  `-`  `-`  `-`  `-`  `-`  | |     they are text
| |                           | |
| |  ,-,                      | |
| |  |X|                      | |
| |  `-`                      | |
| `---------------------------` |
|                               |
`-------------------------------`
```

What would be the best (as in simplest in terms of developer time) way to make this happen?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Set for this blocks - `display: inline-block`, and for main container some width...

```
  .div {
     display: inline-block;
  }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guh5Z/1/

Comment: This is better then the float left solution. Because floating elements will pop out the outer div, unless you specify overflow: hidden on the outer div

Comment: Good catch, @WouterH!  `inline-block` should expand the containing element.  I think the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guh5Z/2/ better portrays the difference, as the height is not fixed.

Comment: i thing that is more 'future' solution, of course u will be have problems with lower IE implementation but this is some kind of compromise ;)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! Is there a way to justify all the divs as well? Not necessary, but would be nice if possible.

Comment: @wrongusername See the [CSS3 text-justify property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-justify.asp).

Comment: this didn't work for me.  It just made the inner divs expand.

Answer (score 4):

You can just apply `float: left` to each of the inner divs.  See the following jsFiddle as an example (try resizing the result pane to see the behavior):

jsFiddle (Live): http://jsfiddle.net/guh5Z/

Source Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #outer {
            width: 90%;
            height: 90%;
            margin: 5%;
            overflow: auto;
            background-color: red;
        }

        .inner {
            float: left;
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            margin: 20px;
            background-color: blue;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <div id="outer">
        <div class="inner">X</div>
        <div class="inner">X</div>
        <div class="inner">X</div>
        <div class="inner">X</div>
        <div class="inner">X</div>
        <div class="inner">X</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works now; not really sure what happened there.  Added the jsFiddle link.

Comment: Please include the code in your answer, as jsfiddle can be down someday :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure why hasn't anyone mentioned `flex-wrap` CSS property:

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-direction: row;
```

For my case this does exactly what the OP asked. And it lets me use flexbox, too.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, wrapping div with `flex-wrap`!

Comment: Now I also know why hasn't anyone mentioned it originally - as it likely didn't exist in 2012. But it does exist and is supported now.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `<ul>` instead if you'll put text instead. Something like this :

CSS:

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```xml
<ul>
  <li>Random text here</li>
  <li>Random text here</li>
</ul>
```

I hope that helps

Comment: That's the same trick as proposed in Jonathan Newmuis' answer.

Comment: Oh I haven't seen Jonathan's answer until now :)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not text, but a combination of text and information contained in a div :( thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: You don't necessarily have to insert text ONLY. You can put nested divs there too.